# 404 when making a get request with axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm getting a 404 request for this:

```
import axios from "axios";

axios
      .get("https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com")
      .then((data) => console.log(data.json()));
```

The error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
createError @ createError.js:16
settle @ settle.js:17
handleLoad @ xhr.js:61
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ App.js:75
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
```

It's because of cors. What is the best way to  fix this?
It's because of cors. What is the best way to  fix this?

Comment: How did you infer it's caused by CORS? It's not mentioned in your error log. If it is indeed so, unless you control the server, you don't have much to do with that, CORS policy is set on the server side

Answer (score -1):

1. Use this server https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a proxy on your request, it solved it for me, for more detail on it [click here](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)
2. or you can try using the fetch api
3. I'd recommend, you use a catch on that Axios request to get more details on the error

Answer (score -1):

Try below code;

```
import axios from 'axios';    

//Create Axios instance
const Instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com",
    timeout: 15000,
    timeoutErrorMessage: 'Your request Timed-out',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});
//Export the Instance if needed


//From a function, use the instance
Instance.get("")
      .then((data) => console.log(data.json()));
```